# Log in to a DC with local user

Tags: windows, powershell, user-accounts

Short but complicated question : is there any way to log on to a Domaincontroler with Servername\Username?

Ive got a Script wich specificly uses a Local Account (since 99% of our Servers are not in a Domain + you can create Local user accounts on almost Every Windows machine, but not on a DC sadly).

So basicly what im asking is : is there a way to trick a DC to accept Servername\Username as a domain login? is there a way by rights? Changing the Script is not an option sadly since the infrastructure behind it is too big to change, and i dont want to add a server specific exception.

Update : It worked on 2 2003 DCs but still no luck with the 2008 DC. is/was there a Change in microsofts server Policy?

the Script part im Using :

```
    $SecurePassWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $($Row['Passwort']) -Force
    $Cred = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList "$($Row['ServerName'])\$($Row['Benutzername'])", $SecurePassWord
    $pssessionoption = new-pssessionoption -operationtimeout 7200000 -IdleTimeout 7200000

    Try {
        $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $($Row['ServerName']) -credential $Cred -sessionOption $pssessionoption -EA Stop
        Remove-PSSession -Session $Session
        }
        Catch [system.exception]
        {
                          write-host "not working"
        }
```

Anybody has an Explanation?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot create a local users on a DC and therefore cannot use local credentials. Ever. This question should really be [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: i feared that. sorry for the wrong forum. im kinda new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Ok now im Confused, i just got this working on 2x 2003 Domain controlers, but not with a 2008 Domain Controller.